# Can't add dependency from library with suffix HEAD-SNAPSHOT

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm following a GitHub project example where the user adds a library dependency in the `build.gradle` file. They have the dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3''

    implementation 'org.xrpl:xrpl4j-client:HEAD-SNAPSHOT'
    implementation 'org.xrpl:xrpl4j-keypairs:HEAD-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

I've tried adding the same dependencies to my project but the last two dependencies are causing the Gradle project to fail to sync.

[image]

[image]

What exactly am I doing incorrectly when trying to import these two dependencies?

The only difference is that my project is java based and the GitHub example is kotlin based, but that shouldn't make any difference right? Because the library I'm trying to import is for Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes exactly as i though , if you check here
https://github.com/nhartner/xrpl4j-android-demo/blob/main/app/build.gradle#L34

He is using mavenlocal() , So by replacing them into

```
implementation 'org.xrpl:xrpl4j-client:2.1.0'
implementation 'org.xrpl:xrpl4j-keypairs:2.1.0'
```

and removing mavenlocal() from repositories , might fix the problem .
unless he did any kind of modification to his local version .

for more reading about maven local
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:case-for-maven-local